# awk change column name as a file name

Tags: awk

I want to replace my 5th column in the file with the file name using awk 
I tried this

```
#!/bin/bash
For i in ls; do
awk '{$5 = "$i"; print}' $i > $i_edit
```

But I don´t know why I can not run it, Do you have any idea where is my error?
it doesn´t like my first line.
 My file is like this inside.
  The name of my file is Balteni_SV_ed2_MT_2016_D_P10_G+C_-4040m.
  Maybe I have to remove the first and last line? But I have a lot of file like this. I don´t want to overwrite but edit it and the separation is space.

```
PROFILE Balteni_SV_ed2_M TYPE 3           unspecified      m  m
 363923.46104 372500.00000    0              4040.000      Balteni_SV_ed2_MT_20          unspecified
 363780.87963 372530.87963    0              4040.000      Balteni_SV_ed2_MT_20          unspecified
 363750.00000 372535.75894    0              4040.000      Balteni_SV_ed2_MT_20          unspecified
EOD
```

I would like something like this:

```
PROFILE Balteni_SV_ed2_M TYPE 3           unspecified      m  m
363923.46104 372500.00000    0              4040.000      Balteni_SV_ed2_MT_2016_D_P10_G+C_-4040m          unspecified
363780.87963 372530.87963    0              4040.000      Balteni_SV_ed2_MT_2016_D_P10_G+C_-4040m          unspecified
363750.00000 372535.75894    0              4040.000      Balteni_SV_ed2_MT_2016_D_P10_G+C_-4040m          unspecified
EOD
```

Comment: You want to do this with every file? Are you trying to overwrite the original files? What do the files look like? Please [edit] your question to provide more details. Note that `For` and `for` aren't the same, and that `for` loops end with `done`.

Comment: So that's your input, what exactly should the output look like? Are those fields fixed width, or tab-separated, or something else?

Comment: awk is not sell. `i` outside of your awk script is a shell variable. `i` inside your awk script is an awk variable. The are completely unrelated to each other except for having a common name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is another way

```
for f in *; do awk '{$5=FILENAME}1' "$f" > "$f"_edited; done
```

to skip the first line add `NR>1` qualifier and to skip the last line you can check the field counts, e.g.

```
for f in *; do awk 'NR>1 && NF>4 {$5=FILENAME}1' "$f" > "$f"_edited; done
```

Comment: I don't think that this produces the expected output.

Comment: did you mean first/last line conditions?  I updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah, but also this will collapse the whitespace in the file. Note that you could also just use `print > (FILENAME "_edited")` in awk to skip the shell loop.

Comment: yes you're right, this collapse the whitespace in the file. But in my case, it's not very important

Answer (score 1):

All you actually need is:

```
awk 'FNR==1{close(f); f=FILENAME"_edit"} {$5=FILENAME; print > f}' *
```

and with your input to not modify the first and last lines:

```
awk 'FNR==1{close(f); f=FILENAME"_edit"} FNR>1 && NF>1{$5=FILENAME} {print > f}' *
```